# Why is column name not going over actual column and creating new columns in dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-3.5

I am assigning column names to a dataframe in pandas but the column names are creating new columns how do I go around this issue?

What dataframe looks like now:

```
                                     abs_subdv_cd  abs_subdv_desc
0  A0001A    ASHTON                              ...             NaN
1  A0002A    J. AYERS                            ...             NaN
2  A0003A    NEWTON ALLSUP                       ...             NaN
3  A0004A    M. AUSTIN                           ...             NaN
4  A0005A    RICHARD W. ALLEN                    ...             NaN
```

What I want dataframe look like:

```
 abs_subdv_cd  abs_subdv_desc
0  A0001A    ASHTON                              
1  A0002A    J. AYERS                            
2  A0003A    NEWTON ALLSUP                       
3  A0004A    M. AUSTIN                           
4  A0005A    RICHARD W. ALLEN
```

code so far:

```
import pandas as pd

###Declaring path###
path = ('file_path')

###Calling file in folder###
appraisal_abstract_subdv = pd.read_table(path + '/2015-07-28_003820_APPRAISAL_ABSTRACT_SUBDV.txt',
                             encoding = 'iso-8859-1' ,error_bad_lines = False,
                             names = ['abs_subdv_cd','abs_subdv_desc'])
print(appraisal_abstract_subdv.head())
```

-edit-

When I try appraisal_abstract_subdv.shape..the dataframe is showing shape as (4000,1) where as the data has two columns.

this example of data I am using:

```
A0001A    ASHTON                                  
A0002A    J. AYERS
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like your data file has another delimiter (not a TAB, which is a default separator for `pd.read_table()`), so try to use: `sep='\s+'` or `delim_whitespace=True` parameter.

In order to check your columns after reading your data file do the following:

```
print(df.columns.tolist())
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a rename function in pandas that you can use to get the column names

```
appraisal_abstract_subdv.columns.values
```

then with those column names use this method to rename them appropriately

```
df.rename(columns={'OldColumn1': 'Newcolumn1', 'OldColumn2': 'Newcolumn2'}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: But the data has no columns so I can not rename it. I just want to name it. 

also when I go and try df.shape, it is only showing one column where there are two. not sure why this is causing it. adding it in main questions

Comment: `appraisal_abstract_subdv.columns.values` to get the names

Comment: I dont know why but file is being read with one column and when I go to rename it give me error "length mismatch:expected axis has 1 elements, new values have two"

not sure why its reading the data file as two columns instead of 1.

Comment: your'e reading it from a .txt file? Are there commas inbetween the columns? There are probably no delimiters in the .txt file so it's reading each row as one column

Comment: Correct reading from text file, but your right no delimiters, I need to fix the data. but will mark you answer correct.